# filter a list by gender

Tags: filters

I am very new to WordPress and I want to filter a list by gender.

Selecting a male option should filter the list to show only males with the relative information.

How can I achieve that?

```
$list = array(
(object) array( 'name' => 'John', 'gender' => 'male', 'job' => 'Farmer' ),
(object) array( 'name' => 'Paul', 'gender' => 'male', 'job' => 'Blacksmith' ),
(object) array( 'name' => 'Adam', 'gender' => 'male', 'job' => '' ),
(object) array( 'name' => 'Mike', 'gender' => 'male', 'job' => '' ),
(object) array( 'name' => 'Jane', 'gender' => 'female', 'job' => 'Baker' ),
(object) array( 'name' => 'Jill', 'gender' => 'female', 'job' => 'Farmer' ),
);
```

Comment: Do you mean server-side/PHP? Client-side/JS? There are some helpers for former, but latter is outside of WP scope usually.

Comment: yes, i mean server-side/php

Comment: Not a WordPress question then. Ask at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @JacobPeattie while this _can_ be solved generically with PHP, WP core does have WP–specific way to do this, so in my opinion this is loosely on topic. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a convenient helper function in WP core called `wp_list_filter()`.

Easy as:

```
$male = wp_list_filter( $list, [ 'gender' => 'male' ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with "old" fashion PHP (besides WP [wp_list_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_filter/)):

> I tend to prefer this kind of solutions as you can get more options.

```
 $only_males = array_filter(
        $list,
        function ($e) {
            return $e->gender == 'male';
        }
    );
```

will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => John
            [gender] => male
            [job] => Farmer
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Paul
            [gender] => male
            [job] => Blacksmith
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Adam
            [gender] => male
            [job] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Mike
            [gender] => male
            [job] => 
        )

)
```